# Overloading classes based on methods

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I want some way to declare the same class multiple times with different methods:

```
class A // Implementation 1
{
    void someMethod();
};

class A // Implementation 2
{
    void someMethod();
    void anotherMethod();
};

class A // Implementation 3
{
    void entirelyDifferentMethod();
};
```

And the basic concept is that the appropriate class A is chosen based on what methods are used. The main use is so I can implement a class with different data structures dependent on the methods that are actually called.

Is there a way to implement this in C++ so that the following would work?

```
A class1;

class1.someMethod(); // class1 is using implementation 1 of class A

A class2;

class2.someMethod();
class2.anotherMethod(); // class2 is using implementation 2 of class A

A class3;

class3.entirelyDifferentMethod(); // class3 is using implementation 3 of class A
```

Comment: I want to create some generic classes but in order to keep them optimized I want the core data structures to be different if some of the features are not in use

Comment: ...and you dont know what type you need at the point of instantiation?

Comment: You can create a base class and let the others inherit from it.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use the Strategy pattern which delegates some activities to a composition instance that can be replaced at runtime to define different behavior.

Comment: I don't want the user of the class to worry about how its implemented. I just want them to use the methods, and the implementation to change depending on what methods they decide to use

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want a client to be able to write `A a;` and then, if they just use `a.someMethod()`, it will be the "first" `A`. But if they also use `a.anotherMethod()`, it will be the second? No, that's not possible. A variable's static type determines what operations are applicable.

Comment: Unfortunately C++ doesn't let you ask "Will this member function be instanciated" and especially not "Will this member function be used on this instance". You can use one class that has all member functions with tricky implementations to detect usage at runtime, but that probably loses you the efficiency you hoped for. You could also ask the questions that C++ doesn't let you to a clang tool instead and write a preprocessor or just brute force which class compiles (using a lot of `auto`). None of the options are particularly good.

Comment: I have even doubts whether you would gain anything from eliminating unused methods from the instances that dont use them. Its not the instances that "carry" the methods (unless you use virtuals, but seems like you dont want that), so I would expect zero gain by using your implementation 1/2/3 instead of one class that has all the methods

Comment: Probably impossible. There may be some absurdly convoluted way to do that using template trickery, but it wouldn't worth the effort.

Comment: @user463035818 I had this idea too. The goal is that you write for example `std::container<T>` and the compiler picks whichever container is most suitable based on the functions called on it, possibly even using profile guided optimizations. I would expect significant performance improvements and very significant compilation and compiler complexity overhead, but C++ just cannot express this.

Answer (score 0):

Template specialization may help. I am not sure what are you aiming for, but try this:

```
template<int N>
class A;

template<>
class A<1>
{
public:
     void f(){std::cout<<"A1 f()"<<std::endl;}
};

template<>
class A<2>
{
public:
     void f(){std::cout<<"A2 f()"<<std::endl;}
     void g(){std::cout<<"A2 g()"<<std::endl;}
};



int main()
{
     A<1> a;
     A<2> b;

     a.f();
     b.f();
     b.g();
}
```

The output is:

```
A1 f();
A2 f();
A2 g();
```

FYI: The compiler cannot deduce the object type from the object's name.